# Replace range of numbers with certain number

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to replace a range of numbers with a certain number. I really tried it hard to code it myself with sed (like sed "s/[33-64]/64/") or awk, but always get wrong results. It tends to replace single digits instead of numbers... What I need would be: Replacing 0-32 -> 32, 33-64 -> 64, 65-128 -> 128, 129-255 -> 255. In between these numbers are IPs, which should stay untouched. I think this command is selecting all, but IPs:

```
sed '/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/! ...  '
```

So I have a file like this:

```
65.74.16.161
232
10.128.8.72
63
10.128.14.13
100
10.128.8.58
32
10.128.4.129
60
10.128.240.18
59
```

and it should look like this:

```
65.74.16.161
255
10.128.8.72
64
10.128.14.13
128
10.128.8.58
32
10.128.4.129
64
10.128.240.18
64
```

Comment: `sed` is a bad way to go. You would have to write some crazy expressions like `'s/\<\([0-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[012]\)\>/32/g'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[33-64]` defines a character class and is a funny way of writing `[3-6]` and does indeed only match a single character — any single digit from 3, 4, 5 or 6.  If you really want to do it with `sed`, and you're concerned with values from 33 to 64, then you have to write it out differently — and much more verbosely.

In part it depends on which version of `sed` you have.  A solution that will work with classic `sed` is:

```
sed -e 's/^[0-9]$/32/' \
    -e 's/^[12][0-9]$/32/' \
    -e 's/^3[012]$/32/' \
    -e 's/^3[3-9]$/64/' \
    -e 's/^[45][0-9]$/64/' \
    -e 's/^6[0-4]$/64/' \
    -e 's/^6[5-9]$/128/' \
    -e 's/^[7-9][0-9]$/128/' \
    -e 's/^1[01][0-9]$/128/' \
    -e 's/^12[0-8]$/128/' \
    -e 's/^129$/255/' \
    -e 's/^1[3-9][0-9]$/255/' \
    -e 's/^2[0-4][0-9]$/255/' \
    -e 's/^25[0-5]$/255/'
```

But, as you can see, it is quite painful.  If you have GNU `sed`, you can use the `-r` option to enable extended regular expressions; if you have Mac OS X or BSD `sed`, you can use the `-E` option to enable extended regular expressions.  Then you can reduce the code above to:

```
sed -E \
    -e 's/^([0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[012])$/32/' \
    -e 's/^(3[3-9]|[45][0-9]|6[0-4])$/64/' \
    -e 's/^(6[5-9]|[7-9][0-9]|1[01][0-9]|12[0-8])$/128/' \
    -e 's/^(129|1[3-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/255/'
```

However, you might do better using `awk`:

```
awk '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/ { if      ($1 <=  32) print  32
                       else if ($1 <=  64) print  64
                       else if ($1 <= 128) print 128
                       else if ($1 <= 255) print 255
                       else                print  $1
                       next
                     }
     { print }'
```

The final `else` clause accurately prints any unexpected values, such as 256 or 999 or, indeed, 123456789.  There are those who would write `1` in place of `{ print }` — the part of the `awk` script that matches and prints the IP addresses.

Comment: Excellent piece of AWK. This shows immediately what the purpose is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. I don´t know what´s the problem, but its all not working on my machine. I tried all the 3 code pieces as well as the two other suggestions, but it is not altering the output, the numbers stay the same. I have mac os x 10.10.3. Could there maybe be a problem with some options or bash versions?

Comment: I was testing on Mac OS X 10.10.4, and copy/pasted the material and your data and was getting the expected output.  And it took a couple of tweaks to get the `awk` correct, so I know that my test sequence was spotting mistakes in the output. My code assumes no blanks; it won't change anything if there are leading or trailing blanks (or if the data file is a DOS format file with CRLF line endings).

Comment: Sorry, it tried it again and it works perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` with some arithmetic:

```
awk '$1 == ($1+0) && $1<=255{$1 = ($1>128)?255:($1>64?128:32 * int(($1+31)/32))} 1' file
65.74.16.161
255
10.128.8.72
64
10.128.14.13
128
10.128.8.58
32
10.128.4.129
64
10.128.240.18
64
```

`$1 == ($1+0)` is a check to determine `$1` is an integer.

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, if you have a value of say 69 (instead of 64), your code prints 96 instead of 128.  In fact, for any value between 65 and 96, it prints 96 when the specification says it should print 128.  You can also have fun with a line containing just 12345.6789; it is converted to 255, which isn't necessarily the correct answer (though there's an argument the value should not be in the data file).

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -vFS=. ' NF == 1 { v=2^int((log($1)/log(2))+0.5); $1 = v>255?255:v; }1' input
```

*Gives:*

```
65.74.16.161
255
10.128.8.72
64
10.128.14.13
128
10.128.8.58
32
10.128.4.129
64
10.128.240.18
64
```