# Replace values within range using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a group of value that I want to replace value within range in shell, from (0.24,0.26) to 0.25

> ### Data Sets
>
> 0.2756685694253216  0.2465880581619878  0.7465232826513566
>     0.7854901474348578  0.7462693536319435  0.7461233186289065
>     0.3040440234554627  0.7469959968223604  0.7470544151095436
>     0.8715102764854729  0.7462219592218707  0.2459733266406937
>     0.2756682582853889  0.7465457641342352  0.2465506594547140

I am aware of the awk command may be helpful as suggested in [Replace range of numbers with certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359954/replace-range-of-numbers-with-certain-number).

And hence I use

```
awk '/^0.[0-9]*$/{if ($1 > 0.24 && $1 < 0.26) print 0.25}{print}' datasets
```

But it only seems to print the whole file..(Probably there is already solved example or wrong syntax, please comment directly.)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The additional print will print all lines...

Comment: @Mahesh But it does not replace the values..

Comment: Can you add desired output in main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be using something more like:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
           if ($i > 0.24 && $i < 0.26) $i = 0.25
       print}' datasets
```

For each field, if it is a value in the given range (is the branching on equality correct?), replace the value with the surrogate; then print the line.

You've not shown any lines with non-numeric data so I removed the filter condition; if you've only told us part of the story, you can put it back, of course.

Given your input broken with at most 4 numbers per line:

```
0.2756685694253216 0.2465880581619878 0.7465232826513566 0.7854901474348578
0.7462693536319435 0.7461233186289065 0.3040440234554627 0.7469959968223604
0.7470544151095436 0.8715102764854729 0.7462219592218707 0.2459733266406937
0.2756682582853889 0.7465457641342352 0.2465506594547140
```

I get the output:

```
0.2756685694253216 0.25 0.7465232826513566 0.7854901474348578
0.7462693536319435 0.7461233186289065 0.3040440234554627 0.7469959968223604
0.7470544151095436 0.8715102764854729 0.7462219592218707 0.25
0.2756682582853889 0.7465457641342352 0.25
```

If you want the alignment preserved more, you have to work a bit harder, probably assigning a string `"0.2500000000000000"` to the field:

```
$ awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
>            if ($i > 0.24 && $i < 0.26) $i = "0.2500000000000000"
>        print}' datasets
0.2756685694253216 0.2500000000000000 0.7465232826513566 0.7854901474348578
0.7462693536319435 0.7461233186289065 0.3040440234554627 0.7469959968223604
0.7470544151095436 0.8715102764854729 0.7462219592218707 0.2500000000000000
0.2756682582853889 0.7465457641342352 0.2500000000000000
$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You are right, there indeed have non-numeric characters and the output went wrong.                                                       awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i > 0.24 && $i<0.26) $i = 0.25 print}' datasets
awk: {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i > 0.24 && $i<0.26) $i = 0.25 print}
awk:                                                                                      ^ syntax error

Comment: I can't guess from a comment what the problem is; please add it to the question, properly formatted.  Which shell are you using on which platform?  I'm assuming a POSIX-like shell (Bash, Korn, Dash, …); a C-shell derivative would say something like "`Unmatched '.`", so I don't think it's that.

Comment: You missed , after value assignment. `$I = 0.25; print`

Comment: With respect to the non-numeric characters, you probably need to test that `$i ~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/` before doing the numeric comparisons.  That looks for floating point numbers with a decimal point, digits before and after it, and an optional sign at the start.  If you need to allow for exponents too (`3.14E29`, etc), then you need a slightly more complex regex, but not horribly so.

Comment: @MaheshKharvi: if you mean semicolon `;` then it depends on whether there's a newline there or not.  In my code, I don't need the semicolon because there's a newline.  If the code is flattened onto a single line, then the semicolon is necessary.  Well spotted.

Comment: You are right, but OP's comment looked like he had it in same line

Comment: @MaheshKharvi: I agree.  That's why I said I can't tell what's up from the comment because the formatting is lost.  Since my answer has now been accepted, I believe that the problem has been resolved — your advice may well have helped Jack.  Thanks.

Comment: That's right about the missing ";", thanks @MaheshKharvi!

Comment: And also great thanks @Jonathan for well illustrated numerical filter. Now it is working! Great joy for my new experience of shell..